# CMake: suppress developer warnings

Tags: compiler-flags, cmake-gui

#### Description:

I am using `cmake-gui` on Ubuntu to compile programs.

I often encountered warning messages for developpers ending by:

```
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

I tried to insert this `-Wno-dev` flag in the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` box but it doesn't suppress the warnings.

#### Questions:

I have now two very simple questions:
**1)** Where exactly should I insert this flag?
**2)** How to separate it from other existing flags (if any) ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably does not solve your problem with the gui but adding the -Wno-dev from command line works.
The flag does not belong to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS that are specific for compiler not for CMAKE.

Instead you can suppress the message setting the cmake_policy